# Using the state change from a useEffect to trigger another useEffect

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

So,i wanted to add a wysiwyg style editor for a project that i'm making and found this reddit clone  video on youtube that has this in it and i was looking through the code(the video is using editor js) and its using this useEffect to trigger another useEffect and it confused me a bit.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      setIsMounted(true)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      await initializeEditor()

      setTimeout(() => {
        _titleRef?.current?.focus()
      }, 0)
    }

    if (isMounted) {
      init()

      return () => {
        ref.current?.destroy()
        ref.current = undefined
      }
    }
  }, [isMounted, initializeEditor])
```

In the above code,he's using the first useEffect to trigger the second one,a couple of doubts i have is,why not initialize the editor in the first effect itself?So,i did the same

```
useEffect(() => {

    const init = async () => {
      await initializeEditor()
    }

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      init()
    }
  }, [])
```

But,doing this causes the editor to be initialsed twice but i fixed it by disabling strict mode.

My question is,why doesn't the editor get initialised twice in the first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because [useEffect runs twice on mount (in development + strict mode)](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#my-effect-runs-twice-when-the-component-mounts)

In the second example code, `initializeEditor` will be called twice, since the useEffect is run twice.

In the first example code, the second useEffect also runs twice on mount but since `isMounted` is `false` initially, the `intializeEditor` function is not called at all.

When `isMounted` becomes true because of `setIsMounted(true)` in first useEffect, the second useEffect is run again (only once this time) since it's dependency i.e. `isMounted` changed. Hence the `initializeEditor` function is only called once.